# node-sqlite3 error when doing an UPDATE statement after an INSERT statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to insert some items via their `itemId`s and `quantities` into my `sqlite3` database, then update these inserted items by comparing them with another table items' `itemId`s.

I've wrapped everything in `Promise`s to try to accomplish this, but haven't been able to get things running.

```
function makeOrderHandler(request, response, data) {
    insertOrder(request, response, data)
        .then(() => updateItemNames(request, response, data))
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Updated items!");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Caught error: "+err);
        }); // end promise chain

} // end makeOrderHandler

function insertOrder(request, response, data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var db = require('./DBManager.js').getPool();

    for(let i = 0; i < data['content'].length; i++) {
      let unit = data['content'][i];

      db.run("INSERT INTO orderedItems"
        + " (itemId, quantity) VALUES"
        + " ($itemId, $quantity);",
      {
        $itemId: unit.itemId,
        $quantity: unit.quantity
      },
      function(err) {
        if(!err) {
          // Could do something here
        } else {
          reject("SQLite3 insert error: "+err);
        } // end else
      }); // end run
    } // end for
    resolve();

  }); // end return
} // end makeOrder

function updateItemNames(request, response, data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var db = require('./DBManager.js').getPool();

    db.run("UPDATE orderedItems, menuItems SET orderedItems.itemName = menuItems.itemName, orderedItems.unitPrice = menuItems.unitPrice WHERE orderedItems.itemId = menuItems.itemId;",
      function(err) {
        if(err) {
          reject("SQLite3 update error: "+err);
        } else if(this.changes == 1) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject("NOTHING DONE!!!");
        } // end else
      } // end error
    ); // end run
    // resolve();

  }); // end return
} // end updateItemNames
```

The error that is thrown is seemingly from the `updateItemNames()` function:

`Caught error: SQLite3 update error: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near ",": syntax error`.

Perhaps I need to restructure my SQL tables or call things in another order? I haven't got a deep understanding of SQL, but I did try the same thing on sqlfiddle and the SQL statements seemed fine there, so this seems like a JavaScript/asynchronous issue. I also tried updating the `orderedItems` table without using a `WHERE` condition to compare against the `menuItems` table and this worked. So it seems an issue is occurring when I'm comparing the `orderedItems.itemId` to the `menuItems.itemId`.

Comment: You can only update one table per update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query to involve subqueries (somehow) solved my problem:

```
db.run("UPDATE orderedItems"
  + " SET itemName ="
  + "     ("
  + "      SELECT menuItems.itemName"
  + "      FROM menuItems"
  + "      WHERE menuItems.itemId = orderedItems.itemId"
  + "     ),"
  + "     unitPrice ="
  + "     ("
  + "      SELECT menuItems.unitPrice"
  + "      FROM menuItems"
  + "      WHERE menuItems.itemId = orderedItems.itemId"
  + "     )"
  + " WHERE"
  + "     EXISTS "
  + "         ("
  + "          SELECT *"
  + "          FROM menuItems"
  + "          WHERE menuItems.itemId = orderedItems.itemId"
  + "         );"
...
```

Like I mentioned, the query worked fine when testing on sqlfiddle with MySQL, so I wonder if the use of subqueries was necessary for SQLite3.